# How to use git after enabling 2FA without writing the token at each operation

Tags: github, github-actions, two-factor-authentication

I had to active 2 factor authentication on my github account and now when I'm doing a push (git push) I need to write my github name and the token generated by 2FA.

Is there a way to avoid writing the token all the time?

Comment: Are you asking about a personal access token?  Also, what operating system and version of Git are you using?

Comment: @bk2204 I got that personal token and I have to write it every time I do a push and I was wondering if there is a way to "save" that token somewhere so I don't have to write it all the time when I do a git push. I'm using Linux Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can use a credential helper to save the username and password (or token) you use so you don't have to enter it each time.  On Linux, this is usually the `libsecret` credential helper.

It's not shipped compiled by default on Debian and Ubuntu, but the source code is shipped in `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret` and can be copied to another directory.  Then you can install the `build-essential`, `pkg-config` and `libsecret-1-dev` packages, and type `make`.  Once built, you can copy the resulting binary somewhere in your `PATH` (such as `~/bin`, if you've set one up appropriately) and then run `git config --global credential.helper libsecret`.

Git will then store your token automatically for future use on GitHub.